# How to boot existing SLES 11 SP4 with SLES 12 SP5 ISO using grub

Tags: azure, suse, sles

We have SMT server in our environment that is running on SLES 11 SP4 and currently hosted on Azure. Now the support for SLES 11 SP4 has ended and so we need to upgrade to SLES 12 SP5 latest service pack. The issue is that there is no way to attach the iso image of SLES 12 SP5 on Azure (or if there is any please let me know) , one way I am thinking to work around is - to copy the SLES 12 SP5 ISO on our SMT server and mount it and  after change the grub settings so that if I boot the server again it should boot with SLES 12 SP5 ISO . This is what I am thinking but I have no idea what edits I have to make to do that ?

If the server would have been on Vmware Vsphere I would have simply attached the ISO and continued with my upgrade but since the server is on Azure it is really becoming difficult. Any helpful solution will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

I thought another option but not sure this will work.
Export SLES11 SP4 OS disk from Azure and use that disk to create a VM in Hyper-V, then attach SLES12SP5 ISO, boot from that and upgrade from SLES11 SP4 to SLES12 SP5.
Once upgrade done then upload the same disk in Azure and attach as boot disk for your server and then boot your server from new updated disk.

I have not tested yet but please let me know if you try this.